# Web.Config Transform Local Properties

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, web.config-transform

I was just wondering if there might be a way to modify your web.config using the transform to change properties based on your local environment. I would like for each developer to be able to have their own local properties set. This tends to be be extremely helpful when debugging locally and you want to change your connection string but don't want to check in those changes.